# Merge duplicate rows and set values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I am  quite new to scripting in google sheets but I searched on this forum and couldnt quite find an answer'.

Via a script of a google ads script developer i have managed to create an export of all search terms activating my google ads. These keywords are getting compared to the keywords currently in my account. This way I can find missing keywords for my account, and underperforming keywords.

This script outputs the keywords to a google sheets document, however if a keyword is present in multiple campaings and or adgroups, a seperate row for they keyword is created for each campaign / adgroup with their corresponding values.

However i would really like to have these values merged into the same row, so that there is only one row per keyword, with their unique values combined into only one value. [This is the current output of script in google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Eaxf.png)

[and this is how i would like to have the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsvkl.png)

I really don't know how i would accomplish this, could anyone please help me out on this one? it would be much appreciated!

The code i am running to get the export is added below.

```
// Add your spreadsheet here
var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'Google sheets url';

// This is quereis minmum number of impressions.
var Impressions_Threshold = 50;

// If the CTR is below the threshold, it will be labeled as "Not excluded and low performing"
var CTR_Threshold = 1;

// If the number of conversions is above the threshold and the query is not added, it will be labeled as "Not added and has conversions"
var Conversions_Threshold = 0;

// Add your email here
var Notify_Me = "email"

function main() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL).getActiveSheet();
    var columns = [
        'CustomerDescriptiveName',
        'ExternalCustomerId',
        'Query',
        'CampaignName',
        'AdGroupName',
        'Impressions',
        'Clicks',
        'Cost',
        'Ctr',
        'Conversions'
    ];

    sheet.clearContents();
    sheet.appendRow(columns);
    sheet.getRange("K1").setValue("Added Or Not");

    // Get all the keywords in all the acccounts
    var allKeywords = [];
    var report = AdWordsApp.report(
        "SELECT AdGroupId, Criteria " +
        "FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT " +
        "WHERE KeywordMatchType = EXACT " +
        "DURING TODAY");
    var rows = report.rows();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        var row = rows.next();
        var KeywordsLower = row['Criteria'].toLowerCase();
        allKeywords.push(KeywordsLower);
    }

    // Get all the search queries in all the accounts
    var positiveKeywords = [];
    var columnsStr = columns.join(',') + " ";

    var SQRreport = AdWordsApp.report(
        'SELECT ' + columnsStr +
        ' FROM SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
        ' WHERE ' +
        ' Impressions > ' + Impressions_Threshold +
        ' DURING 20120215,20180904'
    );

    var rows = SQRreport.rows();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        var row = rows.next();
        positiveKeywords.push(row['Query']);

        for (var i = 0; i < positiveKeywords.length; i++) {
            if ((allKeywords.indexOf(positiveKeywords[i]) === -1) && (row['Conversions'] > Conversions_Threshold)) {
                row.addedOrNot = 'Not Added and has Conversions';
            } else if ((allKeywords.indexOf(positiveKeywords[i]) === -1) && (parseFloat(row['Ctr']) < CTR_Threshold)) {
                row.addedOrNot = 'Not excluded and low performing';

            } else if (allKeywords.indexOf(positiveKeywords[i]) === -1) {
                row.addedOrNot = 'Not Added';
            } else {
                row.addedOrNot = 'Added'
            }
        }
        sheet.appendRow([row['CustomerDescriptiveName'], row['ExternalCustomerId'], row['Query'], row['CampaignName'], row['AdGroupName'], row['Impressions'], row['Clicks'], row['Cost'], row['Ctr'], row['Conversions'], row['addedOrNot']]);
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(Notify_Me,
        'SQR Report',
        'Your SQR report for this month is ready, please visit ' + SPREADSHEET_URL + ' Thanks');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* script this, but it may be better for you in the long-term to leave the export as it is and instead have a second sheet present the data as you wish. I say this as granular row data may be preferable down the line for different analytics.

In a second sheet you can use the Google Spreadsheet formula `Query()` and have that group results by the keyword. You'll know best if you need all the same columns in your presentation sheet.

- [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

If you know any SQLlike database the query structure should be familiar. If not then it's pretty straightforward, but you can read more about it here:

- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: Hi Jonathon,

I did not know that the query function could group values, but how  would one do so for multiple values? the sheet is getting dynamically populated. and from what i see you have to tell google sheets for what values it has to look to group them. Since the sheet is getting populated with over 30000 rows this cannot be done manually

Comment: Oh I got it, Thank you! this is indeed way easier. Thasnk you very much!

Comment: Happy to help - happy also if you accept this is the correct answer. 

Comment: Hi Jonathon (or anyone else),

I almost got everything working as is it should be. Only one thing is that i cannot use the exported data as we go. I have to transform the columns "Cost", "CTR" and "Conversions" into values via several formula's for it to work completely. 

Is it possible to alter the script I posted up here so that the cost and conversions columns are transformed automatically into values (with commas instead of dots and seen by Gsheets as value) and the CTR as percentage?